# Is it possible to programmatically access the NSValueTransformer associated with my cocoa binding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

The reason isn't important, because I know this is bad, but it's just for curiosity.  The better way, what we are going to do is just have the transformer access a shared instance to update a `self` property, instead of somebody else setting it on the transformer.

But is there any way to access the options on a cocoa binding programmatically, and more specifically, access the current transformer?

Comment: Probably.  Have you tried `optionDescriptionsForBinding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access the transformer:

```
options = [[textfield infoForBinding:NSValueBinding] objectForKey:NSOptionsKey];
valueTransformer = [options objectForKey:NSValueTransformerBindingOption];
```